# VSF Unable to get integration template from git repository

Tags: e-commerce, commercetools, vue-storefront

I want to set up a new vue storefront project and I've got this error. I don't know why this is happening, can someone help out in this situation?

```
command: npx @vue-storefront/cli init
? What's your project name? smso
? Choose integration Commercetools
```

ERROR  VSF Unable to get integration template from git repository

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect your frontend application with a commercetools project yet?
You can register for a free trial here: https://commercetools.com/free-trial
And the following documentation describes how to create a project:
https://docs.commercetools.com/merchant-center/projects#create-a-project
So basically just register with your Merchant Center user and then click your initials in the upper right hand corner to create an organisation, a team as well as a project.

Comment: no i have no frontend project yet, i want to create a new one

Answer (score 0):

You might be running the command `vsf init <project_name>` in the wrong directory. It happened to me when I was following along [this URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmwvU.jpg). Compare the below two print screens:

The error I got:
[image: ![enter image description here]

The right way to do it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The commercetools integration is an enterprise solution, so the one in the CLI is a mockup just for knowledge sharing on how to build integrations.

You can check our integrations at https://docs.vuestorefront.io/v2/integrations/